# How to fix GridBagLayout button size

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("450");
        frame.setSize(1000, 600);
        MemberPanel memberPanel = new MemberPanel();
        frame.add(memberPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.TextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MemberPanel extends JPanel{
    private GridBagConstraints c;

    public MemberPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        memberPage();
        //memberPage2();

    }
    public void memberPage() {
        JButton addMovie = new JButton("Add Movie");
        JButton random = new JButton("Random");
        JButton storedData = new JButton("Stored Data");
        JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        JButton search = new JButton("Search");
        TextField searchBar = new TextField(40);
        removeAll();
        repaint();
        revalidate();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(addMovie, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(random, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(storedData, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(settings, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(quit, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20); // side padding
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(searchBar, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20); // side padding
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(search, c);
    }
    public void memberPage2(){
        JButton addMovie = new JButton("Add Movie");
        JButton random = new JButton("Random");
        JButton storedData = new JButton("Stored Data");
        JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        JButton search = new JButton("Search");
        TextField searchBar = new TextField(40);
        removeAll();
        repaint();
        revalidate();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(addMovie, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(random, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(storedData, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(settings, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 20, 0); // side padding
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(quit, c);
    }
}
```

In the constructor of class `MemberPanel` there are two functions `memberPage()` and `memberPage2()`. `memberPage()` is the function that I want to implement but the size of the buttons are all wrong. I want all the buttons except `searchBar` and `search` to be the same size. To see what I mean, uncomment `memberPage2()` and comment out `memberPage()`. How do I keep all the buttons in `memberPage2()`the same size while adding my `searchBar` and `search` button and using the `gridBagLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your question over again several more times, I finally understood what your real problem is. I did not quite get it at first; original answer below (below the line) will not actually solve your problem. Here is your issue:

`GridBagLayout` puts everything into a grid of rows and columns (gridx, gridy). Your "Stored Data" button is the same width as your text field because they are part of the same column. There are a few ways you can fix this, and what exactly you do depends on what exactly you want it to look like.

The simplest (my opinion) answer is to make the text field occupy multiple columns. `GridBagConstraint` has a `gridwidth` field for this.

```
c.gridwidth = 3;
panel.add(txtField, c);
c.gridwidth = 1; // don't forget to put it back after
```

If you do this, remember that the "Search" button then also needs to be in a different column, as the next column to the right of the text field (and the next one after that with a gridwidth of 3) are all occupied by the text field. So either put the text field at gridx=0, or move the search button's gridx over plus 2 more.

---

You generally control the size of the buttons by setting the button's `setPreferredSize(Dimension)`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

c.gridx = x1;
c.gridy = y1;
JButton btn1 = new JButton("Smaller");
btn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
panel.add(btn1, c);

c.gridx = x2;
c.gridy = y2;
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Larger");
btn2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
panel.add(btn1, c);
```

Is that what you are after?

If you want the new size to be relative to the old size, you can get the current size with `Dimension getPreferredSize()`, then you can make the new one use the `width` and `height` from the old one and add or multiply to it.

```
Dimension d = btn1.getPreferredSize();
btn1.setPreferredSize(d.width + 30, d.height);
```

[setPreferredSize](http://javadoc.imagej.net/Java7/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension))

Comment: So ipady and ipadx doesn't control the size? How do I implement ipadx and ipady?

Comment: I'm not saying that ipadx/ipady are not related to size. What I am saying is that to "set the size" of a component (which appeared at first to be specifically what you were addressing), the component's setPreferredSize() is generally the answer, and will also work in other layout managers too. However, see the updated answer. My original answer is not going to help you.

Comment: Thank you. It took a little bit of fiddling around since I'm not familiar with the layout, but I got it to work with the gridwidth